# Live Search with PHP not working correctly on Chrome for Ubuntu

Tags: jquery, linux, google-chrome

I have a webpage with livesearch using php and mysql. It works perfectly in Chrome on Mac and on PC, however it's not completely running on Chrome for Linux (Ubuntu 16.04). When I search for the keywords, it gets the results, however when I click on the result doesn't do anything, when it is supposed to fill several inputs. My guess is something to do with Chrome settings on Linux, but I don't have a clue. Here's my code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid').val(decoded);           

});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchid').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});


jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.telefone').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#telefoneid').val(decoded);         

});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.id').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#id').val(decoded);         

});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.email').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#email').val(decoded);          

});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.nif').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#nif').val(decoded);        
});
});
});
```

Comment: Please remove **" $(function(){ "** from 2nd line and remove **" }); "** from code and then try.

Comment: No success, still doesn't do anything when I click on the result.

Comment: Tried a different link when I had it also saved and it works, something I did not copy correctly to the new link.

Comment: any errors in the developer tool?